# ORA-01000 maximum open cursors exceeded VS 2019

Tags: oracle, visual-studio-2019

We have developped an application in VS2017 targeting an oracle database with oracle client 12. Everything is running smoothly. I compiled the source code in VS2019 with Oracle client 19 targeting the exact same original database, application crashes with ORA-01000 exception. I repeated the exact operation with the original configuration, no problem occured. For me the problem is not on the Oracle database engine because it is working with VS 2017 and oracle client 12. What setting should I look at on the oracle client 19 or on the ODT or in VS 2019 ?

Comment: Have you seen [this related post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28696528/ora-01000-maximum-open-cursors-exceeded-using-oracle-instant-client-and-c-sharp?rq=2)? And [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12192592/java-sql-sqlexception-ora-01000-maximum-open-cursors-exceeded?rq=2)?

Comment: Check that you are closing all the cursors that you open. If, for example, in v12 when you close a pooled connection it implicitly closed the cursors if you had forgotten to do so and then in v19 the behaviour changed to not implicitly closing cursors then your code is going to start leaking cursors. You would need to investigate the behaviour of the drivers you are using and see if something like this is occurring but, if it is, it is **NOT** a bug on the driver; it would be a bug on **YOUR** software that you are not explicitly closing the cursors and were relying on implicit behaviour.,

Comment: I tried each time I create a command object, to close and reopen the connection:        oraCommand = Nothing
        If Not IsNothing(oraConnection) Then
            oraConnection.Close()
            oraConnection.Dispose()
            oraConnection = Nothing
        End If
        Dim ConnectionString As String
        ConnectionString = "Data Source=" + DataBaseName + ";User Id=" + UserName + ";Password =" + passWord + ";pooling = true; Max Pool Size = 1000"
        oraConnection = New OracleConnection(ConnectionString)
        oraConnection.Open()
same reslt

Comment: What is the value, OPEN_CURSORS  , try increasing it and see if that helps., also check V$SESSTAT to get the  counts of open cursors.

Comment: @HimanshuKandpal Increasing OPEN_CURSORS is not a solution, if the programs has a cursor leak; all you are doing is delaying the problem a little while longer...

Comment: You can also check v$open_cursor to see the SQL related to each open cursor.

Answer (score 0):

I finally realised that the oracle client for Oracle 19 was less lineant. For the select statements using executeNoQuery the cursors were closed by the oracle client version 11 but were not with oracle client version 19. We changed the code to use dataAdapter.fill and application runs smoothly now